# EclipseLink 2.7.3 throws QueryException (just like Bug 493235)

Tags: java, eclipselink, multi-tenant

I have a system using multi-tenancy with the `Schema` discriminator, using EclipseLink 2.7.3. I moved to EclipseLink 2.7.3 precisely to avoid this ([Bug 493235](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493235)) (and other) bugs. However, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Exception [EclipseLink-6069] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The field [`database_1`.library.libId] in this expression has an invalid table in this context.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Library.findByReservationId" referenceClass=Library jpql="SELECT l FROM Library l WHERE l.libId = (SELECT r.lib.libId FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservId = :reservId)")
```

My entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Multitenant(value = TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = SCHEMA, contextProperty = MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@Table(name = "library")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Library.findByReservId", query = "SELECT l FROM Library l WHERE l.libId = (SELECT r.lib.libId FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservId = :reservId)")})
public class Library implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "libId")
    private Long libId;
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "libId")
    private List<Reservation> reservList;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Multitenant(value = TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = SCHEMA, contextProperty = MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@Table(name = "reservation")
@XmlRootElement
public class Reservation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "reservId")
    private Long reservId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "lib", referencedColumnName = "libId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Library lib;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "reservation")
    private List<BookReservation> bookReservationList;
    @Transient
    private List<Long> bookIdList;
    ...
}
```

This bug is supposed to have gone away with version 2.7. Am I wrong? Could there be something else going on here? Is this bug haunting EclipseLink 2.7.3 as well?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: First thing I'd do is try this out without multi tenancy to see if the query works or not. It is hard to tell if it is related to 493235 or something else in your code.  Looking at the Reservation class though, it has a libId reference to Library; your query is trying to use r.lib.libId when it should probably use r.libId.libId to work.

Comment: Chris, thank you for your keen eyesight. The names in my original code are different, so I'm afraid I forgot to change libId in Reservation to lib (now edited). So there is no real problem with the query, just my carelessness. I should say that the query normally works. The exception is only thrown sporadically, for no concrete reason. _Maybe_ when many service calls happen almost simultaneously? I am not sure at this point.

Comment: The bug you reference hasn't been fixed - it just included a patch that was not merged into the code base.  In the project I was using this for, I switched away from using named queries to avoid this same issue. Since with MT options, the named queries are re-parsed when obtaining each EntityManager, for us there were no savings using named queries anyway. We switched to using an EntityManagerFactory per tenant and then just using regular JPA persistence options in the end, giving us more control of the tenants and what is cached for each within a VM.

Comment: "The bug you reference hasn't been fixed" What??? Wow... Thanks Chris. I would have never thought of this. I mean, it was a bug, there was a fix... why not include it in the next major version?? Anyway, thank you and thanks for the tip about NamedQueries. It's a real bummer to have to re-write all those queries, but I guess I'll probably have to do it.

Comment: That is the problem with open source - anyone can submit bugs and patches, but it still takes a while for a committer to get the motivation to work it; create and run tests, get merge approval etc. I found the workaround painful and have been switching back to named queries, so I might try the patch overtop our binaries at some point if we go back to using a single EMF. That might be an option for you to; try testing the patch before re-writing anything